# Android + Express + Mongodb

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, express, restful-architecture

Folks

I researched a bunch of posts here, though some of the responses validates my questions, there were a few gaps, and hence posting to get a complete end-to-end validation of my architecture.

I want to build an MVP and want to get some input on the fastest path to make this happen and validation on my technology choices. I can handle Javascript, express-node.js, mongo, have a beginner level experience with android programming, and medium java.

I want an android app that can authenticate users before using android app, then enable user to manage customers and their meta data, manage some documents pertaining to per customer like in CRM apps, send the doc back to customer, and process payments from customer via a payment gateway, and also send some notifications to customers via SMS to do some action "a" "b" "c".

I considered moving to a cloud-based solution rather than local database for obvious reasons. Here is the technology stack I was considering. I need validation that this makes sense and I am not missing something.

## Client side programming

- Android Studio 3.0
- ButterKnife: a view binding library to generate some code
- Retrofit for java interface into restful api
- Android app will talk to restful api/web service powered by node.js

## Server

Express framework + node.js server
passport.js for authenticating
payment gateway: stripe

## CDN

may be amazon cdn to hold some docs, templates, and then hold static urls to that data in mongodb, and use node-aws modules in my express app

## Backend storage

noSQL: Moongose ORM + mongodb
modules: pugm moment

At some point later 5-6 months later, I do anticipate having a offline option. I know this is tricky with mongodb, and couchdb etc might be a better since they have a lite option. The other option was for me to use Google firebase. Or use some thing asymettric sync with SQLlite and mongodb (though I don't like to mix sql and nosql).

Again speed is very important to me.

Please share your thoughts on the technology choices I have made and if I am on the right track, and things I need to worry about. Again I am getting MVP ready, soon want a few customers to try it out, and later go GA in 6-9 months.

Thanks
Suds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best" tech stack for a project. Even if we knew enough about you and the project to make a recommendation (which we don't), none of us have a crystal ball to predict the future, and the technology that seems to fit now may be a very poor fit later.

The best advice I can offer for building an MVP is this: **pick the tech stack that lets you validate your riskiest assumptions as quickly/cheaply as possible.** 
In fact, you should expect to build many MVPs, as [the MVP is not a single product, but a process](https://blog.ycombinator.com/minimum-viable-product-process/).

A few examples:

1. The riskiest assumption for most startups is that users want their product in the first place. The quickest/cheapest way to validate this is often to avoid building anything (which can take months), and instead, just *talk* to potential customers (which can take hours)! The "tech stack" in this case may be no more than a napkin sketch or a few mock-ups created in [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/). If users seem uninterested, you'll have to go back to the drawing board, but at least you only lost a few hours instead of months. On the other hand, if customers start salivating when you show them your sketch, you can go on to the next MVP.
2. The next MVP you do may be a hard-coded, static HTML prototype of your product. Your "tech stack" may be to use [html5up](https://html5up.net/) for free HTML5 templates, [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) for styling, and [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) for hosting. Perhaps when you ask customers for money at this stage, they turn you down. That's a shame, but it only cost you a few days of static prototypes instead of months of coding. On the other hand, perhaps a few users will sign a check at this stage, which is great validation!
3. After that, the next MVP may be to add a dynamic backend behind your HTML. In this case, you may be far better off using a Platform as a Service (PaaS) such as [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or Backend as a Service (BaaS) such as [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) so you don't have to spend time deploying/managing infrastructure. Use whatever data storage they offer and don't worry about scaling or fancy features. If you're *lucky* enough to get some traction, and scaling is becoming an issue, that's a great problem to have!
4. At this point, you will know much more about your problem space, and will be able to decide if a relational DB or NoSQL DB is a good fit for your data model, whether Node is the tech your team knows best, whether PaaS or BaaS still fits your needs or if you need to move to Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) such as [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), and so on. Even at this stage, you still typically want to optimize for moving quickly, so you'll typically pick technologies that (a) your team knows best and (b) have a large community that has built open source libraries you can use for your problem space.

For a more detailed look at these sorts of trade-offs, check out the "Picking a Tech Stack" chapter of *[Hello, Startup](https://www.hello-startup.net/)*.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs Jim (and also Francisco). I already did my first set of wireframes using photoshop and showed it to potential clients. I got lot of valuable input. That made me choose a vertical where I can bring more context and a feasible business model also. 

I also ran a survey post that and have 60% of my customers saying they like it, and no one has said no (the remaining 40% - may be).

The next step now is for me to show them what the product feels like. I agree some quick templating might be a good way to testdrive the concept before investing more time in this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak on the Android side of things, but for the backend yes.

My understanding for the backend you want the following features:

1. User authentication
2. Online payments via [Stripe](https://stripe.com/)
3. Data persistance
4. Data synchronization

---

1. User Authentication

You specified that you are going to use [Passport](https://www.passportjs.org/), but you have not specified a strategy. If you are going to basic local auth (username/password), then you'll want to make sure you follow best practices such as hashing the password.

2. Online payments via [Stripe](https://stripe.com/)

Stripe is easy to work with and fast to get going. Make sure it meets all of your requirements before making the commitment to it.

3. Data persistance

I would strongly recommend against using a NoSQL database such as MongoDB. The reason being is that NoSQL is for non-relational data. SQL databases are meant for relational data which you have described above:

> enable user to manage customers

This would be a 1:N or one-to-many relationship; a user can have many customers.

There will be more relationships defined such as one-to-one or many-to-many which makes SQL the clear choice. If you're looking for speed then look into [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) as a free option otherwise [Amazon Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) would be best.

4. Data synchronization

This is something you will need to spend considerable time with. You have to decide if you want to roll your own solution or use an existing solution such as [Realm Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-platform). Rolling your own solution comes with its own complexities on its own. For example what if user A and user B both have access to the same customers *and* edit them at the same time? How will the mobile apps respond? And many other scenarios can happen.

---

In addition to the above:

- I would not make your Node.js/Express application a traditional monolith application/REST API. Take each feature and make it its own "app" or **microservice**.
- Be mindful of any local, state, country, etc. regulations you may have to follow if you are accepting payments. Stripe has its own to follow and you may very well have another set you need to follow.
- Consider the [Spring](https://spring.io/) framework, specifically the [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) project.

Comment: I was going to use passport with hashing only for now, and using the strategy to passport called local-signup for my MVP. 
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

For database I will look at both 'Aurora as well as Google CloudSQL

Comment: So some next steps I am thinking:
1. Build a throwaway android SQL lite local app to testdrive wireframes, that way I can hit the ground running fast and validate the wireframes
2. Then build an android app that talks to a micro-service based express-node.js service backed by Postgress SQL, or some variant of mysql in hosted form (Aurora/CloudSQL)
3. For payment gateway I will use Stripe, but for local asian countries such as India will look into Bhim/Google Tej